# Teamcity doesn't trigger builds consistently for changes on PR

Tags: teamcity

I have an Teamcity server with a bitbucket server repository. On the Teamcity is a build pipeline which is used to validate pull requests setup. And basically it works as expected. But while new pull requests are triggered within a minute, when I commit changes on a pull request it can take up to an hour until Teamcity has the changes in the build configuration page. As soon as it does find them, it triggers the build as expected.
It also doesn't make a difference if I select the "check for pending changes" in the Actions menu.

Strangely on my other build pipline, which builds changes on the master branch new commits are triggered within the minute as well.

Pull Request Build Feature:
[image]

My branch specifications:
[image]

The "Changes checking" settings:
[image]

And the trigger:
[image]

We use TeamCity Professional 2019.2 (build 71499)

EDIT1: I just realized that there are two different views for changes: one for the branch and one for the pull request. The changes do show up in the branch for the pull request very quickly, but not in the one for the pullrequest.

Branch view:
[image]

Pull Request view:
[image]

As a reference those screenshots where made 16:32.

EDIT2: I used this article to set it up: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2019.2/pull-requests.html

EDIT3: I just found out that I can trigger the build with browser the pull request on the Bitbucket Server page. No idea how that works though.

Comment: are pull-requests/*/  real commits or tags to a real commit?
I am wondering if Teamcity symply doesn't see that the tag has changed

Comment: if "pull-requests/*" is a tag as opposed to a real commit, you need to add:
+:refs/tags/* in your branch spec

Comment: As far as I understand it, is you have a base branch in the ref/heads and when you create a pull request it creates a new branch under ref/pull-requests who is "somehow" linked with with the existing branch. My understand so far is that the pull request build feature keeps track of those, but I don't know if the trigger is only set to a very low frequency.  I also added the article I used to set it up to my origian post

Comment: @fgagnaire just to be sure I added "+:refs/tags/*" to the branch specification, but without any change. Same with "+:refs/pull-requests/*/from " from the documentation.

Comment: your doc says to add a "pull request" "Build Feature". It look like you are adding trigger,
look at that link: https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2019/08/building-github-pull-requests-with-teamcity/
it is for github but the principle should be the same.

tell me if it works, I add a proper answer, for other people with the same question

Comment: I have the pull request build feature added. I think otherwise the build for a newly created pull request wouldn't be triggered aswell. I just ommited the screenshot since I didn't think that there is a lot of information there since I use the default settings. But I added one aswell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219553/discussion-between-fgagnaire-and-npadrutt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is by design of Bitbucket Server:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Change-pull-request-refs-after-Commit-instead-of-after-Approval/qaq-p/194702

TLDR: The Refs on pullrequest branches are not updated immediately, due to performance consideration. The easiest way to trigger it is to view the PullRequest on the Bitbucket Server website.
Comments, and ref updates to the master will also trigger it when I understoot that correctly.

Comment: that is kind of making the feature useless

Comment: At least quite a bit less attractive, yes. I think there are some possible workarounds in the linked forum post though. Although I don't think that I can apply those for my situation.